# How to select a radio based on another and switch?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="crm-radio-is_recur_radio-wrapper" class="crm-radio-wrapper crm-radio-wrapper-200px selected"><input class="" value="" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio"><label for="CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio">One-Time</label></div>

<input class="payment_processor_easy-pay crm-form-radio" value="4" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id">



<div id="crm-radio-is_recur_radio-wrapper" class="crm-radio-wrapper crm-radio-wrapper-200px"><input class="" value="month" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio"><label for="CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio">Monthly</label></div>

<input class="payment_processor_nach crm-form-radio" value="6" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id" checked="checked">
```

I have this 2 sets of button and I would like to automatically switch the radios. Condition is I can select only 1 radio.
For example when I select "CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" button, "CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id" should be selected.

When I switch to CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio "CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id" should be selected.

How to do it in jquery? I have tried the following but it doesnt switch:

```
  $('input[name=is_recur_radio]').change(function() {
  $("input[name=is_recur_radio]:checked").attr("id") == "CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" ? $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=6]').prop("disabled", false) : $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=6]').prop("disabled", true);
  $("input[name=is_recur_radio]:checked").attr("id") == "CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio" ? $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=4]').prop("disabled", true) : $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=4]').prop("disabled", false);
  $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=6]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=4]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Please use `if` for conditional statements, `?:` should be used for conditional values.

Comment: When I render that html I get four radio buttons that are already janky

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. If you have 4 radios you give them the same name to only allow one selection. If that is not what you want then please re-read your description which does not make sense. Then create a [mcve] and change the names to something simpler so we do not have to guess what recur means to you and the script

Comment: @mplungjan It looks like they have two pairs of radio buttons, and they should be correlated. So when you select the first button in one pair, it automatically selects the first button in the other pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two radios:

```html
<input id="r1" type="radio">Radio 1<br>
<input id="r2" type="radio">Radio 2<br>
```

You can use the following code to do whatever you want when one is checked:

```js
// If one is checked, uncheck the other.
$('#r1').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#r2').prop('checked', false);
  }
})

$('#r2').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#r1').prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

To attempt to apply it to your situation:

```
//  when I select "CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" button, "CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id" should be selected.

$('#CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', true);
    $('#CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', false);
  }
})

$('#CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', true);
    $('#CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the accepted answer does what you need, then this is much DRYer

I gave the radios in the divs a class and use that to test

Let me know if the code below also works for you

```js
$(".toggle-radio").on('click, change', function() {
  const isMonth = $(this).is("#CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio");
  $('#CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', !isMonth);
  $('#CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id').prop('checked', isMonth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="crm-radio-is_recur_radio-wrapper" class="crm-radio-wrapper crm-radio-wrapper-200px selected">
  <label><input class="toggle-radio" value="" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">One-Time</label>
</div>

<input class="payment_processor_easy-pay crm-form-radio" value="4" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_4_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id">



<div id="crm-radio-is_recur_radio-wrapper" class="crm-radio-wrapper crm-radio-wrapper-200px">
  <label><input class="toggle-radio" value="month" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">Monthly</label>
</div>

<input class="payment_processor_nach crm-form-radio" value="6" type="radio" id="CRM_QFID_6_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id" checked="checked">
```

Comment: You might not want click in case a radio can be changed through another event?

Comment: Ok added change.,